# Solving a basic linear congruence

Tags: congruences

I have been tasked with solving a linear congruence:

$$-12x\equiv-3\pmod{26}$$

---

How do I do this? I've never done linear congruences with minus signs so I'm quite confused.

Usually I would find the inverse of the LHS and multiply the RHS by the inverse however obviously since we have a negative number, the number isn't in $\mathbb{Z}_{26}$ so we can't find an inverse.

Comment: $-12 = 14$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{26}$, so why are negative signs a problem? But $14$ is even, so it's not invertible modulo $26$.

Comment: Reducing modulo $2$ gives $0 \equiv 1 \pmod 2$, so the equation is inconsistent.

Comment: @T.Bongers Ah so we have $$14x\equiv 23\pmod{26}$$ however again $14$ does not have an inverse so what do I do now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some integer $k$,
$$\begin{align*}
-12x&\equiv -3 \pmod{26}\\
-12x &= -3 + 26k
\end{align*}$$
The left hand side is divisible by $2$, but the right hand side is not, so there is no solution for $x$.